# Error in MySQL v5.7.11 installation after compiling

Tags: mysql, macos, file-permissions

I am getting following error in MAC OS X 10.11 while trying to start mysql server after installation from source code compilation. 
keyring_file is not readable.

I have tried to start server using following command.

```
./mysqld start
```

Following error is generated in terminal.

```
2016-03-24T18:43:50.591772Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-03-24T18:43:50.592053Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
2016-03-24T18:43:50.592091Z 0 [Note] ./mysqld (mysqld 5.7.11) starting as process 3470 ...
2016-03-24T18:43:50.593833Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql/data/Hemens-MacBook-Pro-2.lower-test
2016-03-24T18:43:50.593852Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql/data/Hemens-MacBook-Pro-2.lower-test
2016-03-24T18:43:50.595428Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin keyring_file reported: 'keyring_file initialization failure. Please check if the keyring_file_data points to readable keyring file or keyring file can be created in the specified location. The keyring_file will stay unusable until correct path to the keyring file gets provided'
2016-03-24T18:43:50.595860Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-03-24T18:43:50.595866Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2016-03-24T18:43:50.595881Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2016-03-24T18:43:50.595884Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-03-24T18:43:50.596157Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2016-03-24T18:43:50.596319Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-03-24T18:43:50.605257Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2016-03-24T18:43:50.615154Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-03-24T18:43:50.631296Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-03-24T18:43:50.638315Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2016-03-24T18:43:50.638358Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
2016-03-24T18:43:50.638364Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.
2016-03-24T18:43:50.638369Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
2016-03-24T18:43:50.638373Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.
2016-03-24T18:43:50.638377Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile './ibtmp1'
2016-03-24T18:43:50.638381Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to create the shared innodb_temporary
2016-03-24T18:43:50.638385Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Cannot open a file
2016-03-24T18:43:50.954042Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2016-03-24T18:43:50.954098Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2016-03-24T18:43:50.954119Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2016-03-24T18:43:50.954126Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2016-03-24T18:43:50.954141Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2016-03-24T18:43:50.954223Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2016-03-24T18:43:50.954232Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'keyring_file'
2016-03-24T18:43:50.954507Z 0 [Note] ./mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Answer (score 2):

If you check the [keyring_file_data mysql manual entry](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_keyring_file_data) you will see what this option means:

> The path name of the data file used for secure data storage by the
>   keyring_file plugin. The file location should be in a directory
>   considered for use only by the keyring_file plugin. For example, do
>   not locate the file under the data directory.
>
> Do not use the same keyring_file data file for multiple MySQL
>   instances. Each instance should have its own unique data file.
>
> The default file name is keyring, located in a directory that is
>   platform specific and depends on the value of the INSTALL_LAYOUT CMake
>   option, as shown in the following table. To specify the default
>   directory for the file explicitly if you are building from source, use
>   the INSTALL_MYSQLKEYRINGDIR CMake option.

You will also see a default value how various Linux distributions handle it.

`/var/lib/mysql-keyring/keyring`

So the answer should be it is safe to ignore. However should you wish innodb file encryption my.cnf should look something like this:

```
[mysqld]
keyring_file_data = /var/lib/mysql-keyring/keyring
```

However this probably won't solve your problem.

1. it's a question not belonging to stackoverflow but perhaps serverfault.
2. it's a permissions issue. Did you chown the mysql data directory to the user mysqld is running under?